# how to convert a string into a palindrome with minimum number of operations?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, levenshtein-distance

Here is the [problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=114&page=show_problem&problem=1680) states to convert a string into a palindrome with minimum number of operations. I know it is similar to the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)
 but I can't solve it yet

For  example, for input `mohammadsajjadhossain`, the output is `8`.

Comment: A nice Code Golf too ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perform Levenshtein distance on the string and its reverse. The solution will be the minimum of the operations in the diagonal of the DP array going from bottom-left to top-right, as well as each entry just above and just below the diagonal.

This works because the entries along the diagonal represent the minimum edits required to make the first i and last N-i characters of the string equal and the entries just above and just below represent the minimum for strings ending up with odd-length where the middle (left-over) character doesn't match against anything.

Comment: @TonyK dynamic programming array

Comment: can you explain why you go from the bottom left to top right not the top left to bottom right?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to compute a limited number of Levenshtein distances, one for each possible palindrome pivot point. A pivot point can be a letter or it can be between two letters, so a string of length n has 2n-1 pivot points. For each pivot point, you calculate the Levenshtein distance of the characters before the pivot point and the reverse of the characters after it:

`(m)ohammadsajjadhossain: Levensthein("", "niassohdajjasdammaho")`
`m ohammadsajjadhossain: Levensthein("m", "niassohdajjasdammaho")`
`m(o)hammadsajjadhossain: Levensthein("m", "niassohdajjasdammah")`
`mo hammadsajjadhossain: Levensthein("mo", "niassohdajjasdammah")`
`mo(h)ammadsajjadhossain: Levensthein("mo", "niassohdajjasdamma")`
`moh ammadsajjadhossain: Levensthein("moh", "niassohdajjasdamma")`
etc.

Now just take the minimum of these distances. If speed is important, you can optimise away many of these calls.